# QGIS - Moving vector layer relative to world map

Tags: qgis, vector-layer, qgis-3

I have a shapefiles with coordinates that are supposed to be in EPSG:4326 but seem to be located at a totally wrong place on the planet. I confirm that by adding an osm layer to. Can I somehow move my original layer relatively to the osm layer to the correct place on the planet and then, save it?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the coordinates and approximate real position where the item should be located? Maybe it is some simple issue like switched lon/lat etc.

Comment: The coordinates are:  2577139.0,5622893.8

Comment: Real position is approximately here: 779647,6792358

Comment: I do not think it is EPSG:4326: http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/

Comment: it is rather EPSG:3857 http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/7483/ or some kind of UTM. Which country should it be?

Comment: it should be germany, but it is in romania currently

Comment: if it is from some official sources it might be Gauss-Kruger system: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauß-Krüger-Koordinatensystem with EPSG code 31466-31469 depending on the zone - you can check it here on the map: http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/31466/ it also shows the coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can: Allow editing for that layer, mark all features and drag them happily about.

But should you? It will be hard to determine, whether everything is where it is supposed to be in the end. So, first check if you got the CRS right, got your projects CRS right and so on.

Comment: I can mark them, but what do I have to click in order to "drag them happily about"?

Comment: "Move feature" in the Advanced Digitizing Toolbar.

Comment: Your issue sounds like a CRS/projection issue. Once you find the correct CRS the features will be in the correct locations. Don't try to fix it with the "move feature" tool, because it changes the source file and you won't be able to undo your changes.